# Why does $\frac{|x|}{x^2}$ reduce to $\frac{1}{|x|}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This simplification confused me:
$$.....=\frac{|x|}{x^2} = \frac{1}{|x|}$$

I get cancelling a degree of x, but why must you introduce the abs. val sign in the denominator?  Is it because the left side is guarateed to be positive, so you must retain that in the final expression ?

Comment: Yes that's why.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that $x^2=|x|^2$. Then you just cancel one of the $|x|$ out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want, you can look at is like this: $$\frac{|x|}{x^2} = \frac{|x|}{|x|^2} = \frac{1}{|x|}$$

Comment: Of course $x\neq 0$, however; the op didn't say anyhing.

Comment: Ok, so I can't just "cancel" |x| against a bare x.  I should really make them the same thing with your intermediate step, and then cancel identical |x|'s.  Thanks!

Comment: No, you cancel $|x|$ with a "bare" $x$, not without knowing whether or not $x$ is negative.  You're welcome!

Comment: Then why would I bother introducing the || on the bottom?  I have cancelled a bare x, and there is one left.  Your response makes no sense.

Comment: @JackOfAll  My comment immediately before your most recent comment should have been (in response to your second comment) "No, you canceled |x| with a "bare" x, without knowing whether or not $x$ is negative. If $x \lt 0$, $\dfrac{|x|}{x \cdot x}$, and you simply canceled an x from top and bottom, you get $\frac{1}{x} \lt 0$.

Comment: ...which is impossible because given $\frac{|x|}{x^2}$, the result needs to be greather than zero

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{|x|}{x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x^2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{1}{|x|}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\left|x\right|=x$ if $x>0$ and  $\left|x\right|=-x$ if $x<0$

if $x>0$ we will have $\frac{x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}$

if $x<0$ we will have $\frac{-x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x}$

So, $\frac{\left|x\right|}{x^2}=\frac{1}{\left|x\right|}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is because $$|x^2|=|x|^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $\forall x\in\Bbb{R},\, x^2=|x|^2$.

Indeed if $x\geq 0$ one has $|x|=x$ and the result follows immediately.

Now if $x\lt 0$ one has $|x|=-x$ and $|x|^2=(-x)(-x)=x^2$